# python maya: Loop through curve vertex and fillet each

Tags: python, maya

All I'm wanting to do is create a spline using random points, then pass through the spline adding fillers to the available curve vertex.

Just doing a basic fillet in maya seems pretty setup heavy so I'd like to do it through code just looping through the selected splines vertex.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
path = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 6), (5, 0, 6), (9, 0, 9)] )
```

I know that you can fillet a corner based on a radius by doing the following..
1. Create a curve 
2. Select 2 'Curve Points' with each one being on a different segment
3. Run the Curve Fillet with 'Trim' and 'Join' on with the desired radius size.

What I'm wondering is if there is to possibly apply this approach and fillet all segments of a spline.

[image]

UPDATED:
This is what I have so far and it doesn't want to fillet more than once why is that?

```
#maya has a shape node for every transform object
#cmds.ls(sl=True, t="transform")

import maya.cmds as cmds
import random

a = cmds.spaceLocator(n='pipeCtrl_00')
b = cmds.spaceLocator(n='pipeCtrl_00')
c = cmds.spaceLocator(n='pipeCtrl_00')
d = cmds.spaceLocator(n='pipeCtrl_00')
cmds.xform(a, t=(0,0,0) )
cmds.xform(b, t=(0,0,-6) )
cmds.xform(c, t=(6,0,-6) )
cmds.xform(d, t=(6,0,-12) )


#select all the locators you want to make curves on
items = cmds.ls(type='locator') #cmds.ls(sl = True)
locList = maya.cmds.listRelatives(items, type='transform', parent=True)
sorted(locList)
crvList = []

#run locators through a loop and make a curve segment from 1 to another.
for index in range(0,len(locList)-1):
 crvName = "myCurve"+str(index) 
 aLocPos = cmds.xform(locList[index], q = True, t = True)
 bLocPos = cmds.xform(locList[index+1], q = True, t = True)
 cmds.curve(d=1,n=crvName, p=[(aLocPos[0], aLocPos[1], aLocPos[2]), (bLocPos[0], bLocPos[1], bLocPos[2])] )
cmds.select("myCurve*")
crvList=cmds.ls(sl=True)

#Curve fillet each segment section with random radius.
#for index in range(0,len(crvList)-1):
 #aCrv = crvList[index] 
 #bCrv = crvList[index+1]
 #randRadius = random.randrange(1, 3)
 #cmds.filletCurve(aCrv, bCrv, r=randRadius)
 #aCrv=cmds.ls(sl=True)

#Curve fillet each segment section with random radius
for idx in range(0,len(crvList)-1):
 curveA = crvList[idx]
 curveB = crvList[idx+1]
 randRadius = random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

 m = cmds.filletCurve(curveA, curveB, r=1.5 , cir=True, t=True, jn=True)
```

Comment: Yes and no. Its a linear spline so it can not contain round segments. So how do you want to get it done? Tur it into a higher order spline (bezier or rational  b-spline) with duplicate points or separate curves? PS: Beziers can not make round segments, just approximately round ;)

Comment: I can fillet the corners on this curve by hand. Why can't I do it through code then.

Comment: Thats not the question the question is what result do you want. Code could generate 3 different kinds of results which is it your using when your making the rounds manually. They are quite different in use. Also do you want to keep history or not?

Comment: I do not need to keep the history. All I'm looking to do is take an existing spline created 'like the yellow one above' and then apply a fillet to the corners with a specified radius. Which results in the curvestill being one solid curve.